# Open an external page as an iframe within a docusaurus site

Tags: iframe, tableofcontents, docusaurus

I want to be able to provide a link on my docusaurus ToC pointing to an external page (in this case it's a particular method in an API docs portal), such that the page loads within an iframe on the docusaurus site, so the ToC is still present, but the external page is displayed. Is this possible in docusaurus or any of the well known markdown or rst based doc tools?